# Paley-Wiener type integral: Conditions for the integrand $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian Motion with $B_0=0$. Then define the stochastic integral for $f \in C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ ($f$ does not have to be in $BV$) via an integration by parts formula, involving a "normal" Riemann-type integral:
$$
\int_0^1 f(s)dB_s=f(1)B_1-\int_0^1f'(s)B_sds
$$
For this type of stochastic integral, there is supposed to hold the isometry:
$$
\mathbb{E}\ [\big(\int_0^1 f(s)dB_s)^2    ]=\int_0^1 f(s)^2ds
$$
Using lenghty calculations, involving the identites $\mathbb{E}[B_r B_s]=\min(r,s)$, Fubinis Theorem, splitting up integrals, finding a closed "form" for $\min(s,r)$ under the integral as well as $\frac{d}{ds}f(s)^2=2f'(s)f(s)$ and the integration by parts formula $\int_a^b f'(s)s=f(s)s|_a^b-\int_a^b f(s)$, I could not get the desired result. Instead, I got stuck with terms involving $f(1)$, not involving a square (the squares could have canceled out with $\mathbb{E}[B_1^2f(1)^2]=f(1)^2$).
My question is: Is there any type of (boundary) conditions required for the functions that can be integrated via this stochastic integral? A condition like e.g. $f(1)=0$ would be the simplest way to provide a solution. I am aware that my condition mentioned above does not seem to be a necessary condition, as the constant case $f(s)=c \neq 0$ shows.
Edit: For clarification, the leftover term had the form $f(1)\int_0^1 f′(s)sds$, see the answer by zhoraster for more details.

Comment: I think the best you can do is ask that the difference between the two is $0$, usually we ask that $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using lenghty calculations ... I could not get the desired result

Let us try: 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(1)B_1 -\int_0^1 f'(s) B_s ds\right)^2 \right] = f(1)^2 - 2f(1)\int_0^1 f'(s) s\,ds\\
+ 2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f'(s)f'(u) \min(s,u)ds\,du \\
= f(1)^2 - 2f(1) \int_0^1 f'(s) s\,ds + 2\int_0^1 f'(s) s \int_s^1 f'(u) du \, ds \\
= f(1)^2 - 2f(1) \int_0^1 f'(s) s\,ds + 2\int_0^1 f'(s) s\big(f(1)-f(s)\big)ds \\
= f(s)^2s\bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 2f'(s)f(s) s\,ds = \int_0^1f(s)^2 ds.
$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the crossterm, it should be $2 f(1)B_1 \int_0^1 f'(s)B_s ds$ and this term has zero expectation since $\mathbb{E}[f(1)B_1]=0$. This leads to a leftover term $f(1) \int_0^1 f'(s)s ds $.

Comment: No. It's $2f(1) \int_0^1 f'(s) \mathbb{E}[B_1 B_s] ds = 2f(1) \int_0^1 f'(s) s\, ds$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that!